# Launching a Edit Form from a GridButtonColumn

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, telerik, radgrid

I have a class that defines a Hierarchical RadGrid that I will be using application wide. This grid has many column so this is the best implementation for me, as I will be overriding specific characteristics of the grid based om implementation.

The grid will function in a different manner based on the access level of the user. On a 'basic user level' they will have a Add New Item/Edit Item on the parent grid and Edit, Reject(delete), Approve(Update) on the Child Grid

The next level will be a 'Approver' role. They will NOT have Add New Item/Edit Item on the parent grid and will only have Reject(Edit) on the child. The edit action that the user will take in this role when rejecting an item is that they will be required to enter a comment through a user control that will be launched when the click the reject button. The problem that I am having is that the custom user control is not displaying for a DetailTableView.EditFormSettings when using a GridButtonColumn as the firing event. Any thoughts? TIA

```
private void SubmittedBatchesRadGrid_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
{
    GridDataItem _dataItem = e.Item as GridDataItem;
    if (_dataItem == null) return;

    if (e.Item.OwnerTableView.Name == "SubmittedBatchesRadGrid_ChildGrid")
    {
        SetChildGridCommandColumns(sender, e);
        return;
    }

    if (_dataItem.KeyValues == "{}") { return; }

    SetMasterGridCommandColumns(sender, e, _dataItem);

}

private static void SetChildGridCommandColumns(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
{
    const string _jqueryCode = "if(!$find('{0}').confirm('{1}', event, '{2}'))return false;";
    const string _confirmText = "<p>Rejecting this adjustment will mean that you will have to also reject the batch when you are done processing these items.</p><p>Are you sure you want to reject this adjustment?</p>";
    ((ImageButton)(((GridEditableItem)e.Item)["PolicyEditRecord"].Controls[0])).ImageUrl = "/controls/styles/images/editpencil.png";
    ImageButton _btnReject = (ImageButton)((GridDataItem)e.Item)["DeleteTransaction"].Controls[0];

    _btnReject.CommandName = "Update";
    _btnReject.ImageUrl = "/controls/styles/images/decline.png";
    _btnReject.ToolTip = "Reject this item";
    //_btnReject.Attributes["onclick"] = string.Format(_jqueryCode, ((Control)sender).ClientID, _confirmText, "Reject Adjustment");
}

private void SubmittedBatchesRadGrid_DetailTableDataBind(object sender, GridDetailTableDataBindEventArgs e)
{
    e.DetailTableView.EditFormSettings.EditFormType = GridEditFormType.WebUserControl;
    e.DetailTableView.EditFormSettings.UserControlName = "/Controls/RejectedAdjustmentComment.ascx";
    e.DetailTableView.EditMode = GridEditMode.PopUp;

    e.DetailTableView.CommandItemSettings.ShowAddNewRecordButton = false;
    GridDataItem _dataItem = e.DetailTableView.ParentItem;
    e.DetailTableView.DataSource = AdjustmentAPI.GetAdjustmentsByBatch(Convert.ToInt32(_dataItem.GetDataKeyValue("BatchID").ToString()), PolicyClaimManualAdjustmentCode);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I thought I would share my solution in case anyone else needs it.

I was barking up the wrong tree with the edit control. Even though a comment is part of the dataset in the RadGrid I don't want to edit the existing record. I decided to create a usercontrol to handle the process. The RadWindow does not take .ascx pages directly so I started with a .aspx wrapper page and inserted the control there. Then I changed the OnClientClick event to launch the RadWindow loading the new aspx file passing the parameters I needed to the usercontrol. The usercontrol saves the comment to the database and updates the record status and then closes.

I modified this section from above:

```
    private static void SetChildGridCommandColumns(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
    {
        ((ImageButton)(((GridEditableItem)e.Item)["PolicyEditRecord"].Controls[0])).ImageUrl = "/controls/styles/images/editpencil.png";
        ImageButton _btnReject = (ImageButton)((GridDataItem)e.Item)["DeleteTransaction"].Controls[0];
        int _manualAdjustmentId = Convert.ToInt32(((GridDataItem)e.Item)["ManualAdjustmentId"].Text);
        int _manualAdjustmentBatchId = Convert.ToInt32(((GridDataItem)e.Item)["ManualAdjustmentBatchId"].Text);

        _btnReject.ImageUrl = "/controls/styles/images/decline.png";
        _btnReject.ToolTip = "Reject this item";
        _btnReject.OnClientClick = String.Format("OpenRadWindow('/controls/RejectedAdjustmentComment.aspx?manualAdjustmentId={0}&manualAdjustmentBatchId={1}', 'CommentDialog');return false;", _manualAdjustmentId, _manualAdjustmentBatchId);
    }

    private void SubmittedBatchesRadGrid_DetailTableDataBind(object sender, GridDetailTableDataBindEventArgs e)
    {
//I deleted this section
        e.DetailTableView.EditFormSettings.EditFormType = GridEditFormType.WebUserControl;
        e.DetailTableView.EditFormSettings.UserControlName = "/Controls/RejectedAdjustmentComment.ascx";
        e.DetailTableView.EditMode = GridEditMode.PopUp;
//

        e.DetailTableView.CommandItemSettings.ShowAddNewRecordButton = false;
        GridDataItem _dataItem = e.DetailTableView.ParentItem;
        e.DetailTableView.DataSource = AdjustmentAPI.GetAdjustmentsByBatch(Convert.ToInt32(_dataItem.GetDataKeyValue("BatchID").ToString()), PolicyClaimManualAdjustmentCode);
    }
```

I added this to the page with the datagrid:

```
<telerik:RadWindowManager ID="SubmittedBatchesWindow" runat="server">
    <windows>
            <telerik:RadWindow ID="CommentDialog" runat="server" Title="Rejected Agjustment Comment Dialog"
                Height="350px" Width="440" Left="250px" ReloadOnShow="false" ShowContentDuringLoad="false"
                Modal="true" VisibleStatusbar="false" />
        </windows>
</telerik:RadWindowManager>
```

I created a new aspx file and inserted the new ascx control inside

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<telerik:RadScriptManager ID="RadScriptManager1" runat="server">
</telerik:RadScriptManager>
<uc:RejectedComment id="RejectionComment1" runat="server" />
</form>
```

I added my code behind for the update in the ascx file, the javascript for the front end

```
<script language ="javascript" type ="text/javascript" >   
    //<![CDATA[
    function GetRadWindow() {
        var oWindow = null;
        if (window.radWindow) oWindow = window.radWindow; //Will work in Moz in all cases, including clasic dialog
        else if (window.frameElement.radWindow) oWindow = window.frameElement.radWindow; //IE (and Moz as well)

        return oWindow;
    }

    function CancelEdit() {
        GetRadWindow().close();
    }

    //]]>
</script>
```

and last but not least closing the window after a successful update in the button click event;

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "", "CancelEdit();", true);
```

I hope someone else finds this useful. It took me several hours hunting the telerik site to find this piece by piece.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just need to use `OnClientClick` instead, and return the value of the confirm dialog.

```
_btnReject.OnClientClick = "return confirm(\"Are you sure you?\");"
```

RadAjax has a little quirk when it comes to confirm dialogs, so you may need to use this instead:

```
_btnReject.OnClientClick = "if (!confirm(\"Are you sure?\")) return false;"
```

Comment: Hey James, Thanks I have that part working ok, only now the requirements are that they add a comment when rejecting a item. So I am reinventing. I was able to get this to work with JavaScript and a aspx form but I would like to tie in the built in functionality to load a usercontrol much in the same way you would with an custom edit form.